# VCRedist compatibility across VS Updates, library linking and dll usage

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, vcredist

I know, the VRedists are not compatible between major versions of Visual Studios (2013 is not compatible with 2015 and VCRedist of 215 is needed to install because of different STL implementations - am I right?).
However, I am not sure, what about the minor versions - Updates.

Let's say, we have two developement environments:

a) VS 2015 Update 2 - 14.0.25123.00 with VCRedist *14.0.23918*
b) VS 2015 Update 3 - 14.0.25421.03 with VCRedist *14.0.24210*

1)
I have a lib / dll (particullary OpenCV 2.4.13) **built by VS 2015 Update 2** (environment a) ), can be this library **linked** with a program **in VS 2015 Update 3** (environment b) )?
Can user safely run the program with VCRedist 14.0.23918 installed or is needed to install VCRedist 14.0.24210?

and reversed situation...

2)
The lib / dll is **built by VS 2015 Update 3** (environment b) ), can be this library **linked** with a program **in VS 2015 Update 2** (environment a) )?
Can user safely run the program with VCRedist 14.0.23918 installed?

Answers are very appreciated.

Comment: You can't get a warranty here.  The only known Update 3 issue right now is an obscure MFC problem.

Comment: I can't get warranty in SW development at all ;-) Do you mean https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2892501/new-vc-runtime-14-0-24210-0-breaks-mfc-app-built-with-vs-2015-update-2
It seem it is a bug, however, that is not point of my question. I meant the situations described above as general methods regardless of VC bugs.

Comment: Microsoft never makes a breaking update to a service release.  Knowingly.  That's what you will have to work with.

Comment: Thanks, so in other words, to be sure... I can mix the libs of different Updates, right? In both cases, 1) and 2).
From this "A more-severe kind of change, the breaking change can affect binary compatibility, but these kinds of binary compatibility breaks only occur between major versions of Visual C++." it seems to be as you say. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt723604.aspx)